# Linux::Linux version upgade command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

I use linux ubuntu 10.4.

After some removal, my linux is out of order.

It is a big trouble for me.

I couldn't use X window until now.

So I just should use only tty (text only).

I want to upgrade linux version other than application.

"sudo apt-get upgrade" is for application.

I don't need it.

Could you tell me some command upgrading linux version.

10.04 ---> 12.04

Comment: I believe it's `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: It looks impossible for me because of distroyed network system but I appreciate your help! Thanks  all.

Comment: I learn new things from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your distro to the newest in repository:

Update and upgrade your apt-get modules:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then begin the upgrade process:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

[cit.](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)

Comment: Auto removal make my system destroyed... It doesn't work but I appreciate your help! Have a nice day~ It got dark here, South Korea. T.T